# TypeORM Find all rows in a column from an array of values that are dependant exclusively in 1 query

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I found that there is an `In` option in `typeorm` to allow you to search in a column from values in an array, but the array values are searched independently or considered as an OR. I would like to find out if the result could only be valid if all those values in the array exist in the repository.

In a query like such:

```
const foundPckgs = await this.packageServices.find({
                where: {
                    id: In(packagesIds),
                }

            });
```

Where `packagesIds` is an array of Ids.

The problem with this is that this query will return an array of the existing Ids. So if I only have an array with 3 ids, but only 2 exist in the database, it will only return an array with 2 entries.

Is there a way to treat those search values in the array as, if one does not exist, the query returns an error/won't be accepted? Only in 1 query? Basically like

```
where {id: packageIds[0], id: packagesId[1], id: packagesIds[2]}
```

A workaround would be simply to `findOne` for each id of the array, but that's 3 queries.
Or another Idea I have is to compare the length of the query result VS the `packageIds`' one.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a where object like
const obj = {id: packageIds[0], id: packagesId[1], id: packagesIds[2]}
using loop. then you can place this in where clause.
another way use map if can not find one then don't execute any more just break.
But to me length checking is good solution so far.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How would you exactly be able to build the query from a for loop?